# Jekyll won't parse Markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I'm running Jekyll on Windows 8.1 and can't get Jekyll to parse any Markdown on my site; it just gets pasted as plaintext on the page. However, making a new site with `jekyll new blog` and running it with `jekyll serve` works just fine, including Markdown parsing, so it's not my setup. I've cut my site down to almost nothing:

`/_layouts/default.html`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        {{ content }}
    </body>
</html>
```

`/index.html`:

```
---
layout: default
---

{% for post in site.posts %}
    {{post.content}}
{% endfor %}
```

`_config.yml`:

```
name: sample blog
```

The result is un-parsed Markdown output. Interestingly, code blocks marked with `{% highlight c%} {% endhighlight %}` are wrapped in `<pre>` tags, but that's it. I've been banging my head against the wall for hours and haven't found a fix, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. My posts were `.markup` instead of `.markdown` files. Words cannot describe how dumb I feel after taking four hours to notice that.